# jQuery click() add href to a-tag

Tags: jquery, url, geolocation, jquery-events, attr

When I click on the `GPS-link` then I try implementing the `url` in the `a` tag.
But it does not work!

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  /* add geolocation */
  $("a.target").click(function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else
    {
       alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
  function showPosition(pos){
     var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
     var lon = pos.coords.longitude;

     /* GPS link */
     $("a.target").attr("href", 
            "http://dev.market-locator.com/geolocation-lijst?distance[latitude]="
            + lat + "&distance[longitude]=" + lon
            + "&distance[search_distance]=20&distance[search_units]=km");
   }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<a class="target">Link</a>
...
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to go to the `http://dev.market-locator...` url on click of that link?

Comment: Yes, the url filtered a list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      /* add geolocation */
      $("a.target").click(function(){
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          showPosition(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
      });
  });

 function showPosition(pos){
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var lon = pos.coords.longitude;

    /* GPS link */
    $("a.target").attr("href", "http://dev.market-locator.com/geolocation-lijst?distance[latitude]=" + lat + "&distance[longitude]=" + lon + "&distance[search_distance]=20&distance[search_units]=km");
    window.location.href = "http://dev.market-locator.com/geolocation-lijst?distance[latitude]=" + lat + "&distance[longitude]=" + lon + "&distance[search_distance]=20&distance[search_units]=km"; //add this line
}
```

Function should be define outside of the the `.ready()` function.

Comment: Now i have an other problem. When I click then the function activate and the second click go to the url. Is it possible do this in 1 click??

Comment: @Tuxy I have edited the answer check that and this will work.

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Sorry but i'm new on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your `showPosition` function requires parameter `pos` which it doesn't receive on call.

Maybe, something like this would work?

```
showPosition(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition());
```

Answer (score 0):

First it's maybe because you don't closed properly your click function :

```
  $("a.test").click(function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  });
```

Comment: The first answer works, but it's right, i forgot to close the function.